# Why can not I submit a double form to the database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I created a form view and when I want to save a form with two modules I see "IntegrityError". Please help, Thank you in advance

```
class Place(models.Model):
    LocalName = models.CharField('Nazwa Lokalu', max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField('Link', max_length=100, default="")
    LocalImg = models.ImageField('Zdjęcie Lokalu', 
    upload_to='Place/static/locals/img', blank=True, max_length=20000)
    LocalAdress = models.CharField('Adres', max_length=500)
    LocalNumberPhone = models.CharField('Numer telefonu', max_length=9)
    LocalHours = models.TextField(verbose_name='Godziny otwarcia', 
    max_length=20000)


    def get_aboslute_url(self):
        return reverse("place:place_create", kwargs={'id': self.id})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Lokal"
        verbose_name_plural = "Lokale"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.LocalName

class Menu(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="place", default="")
    Dinner = models.CharField("Nazwa potrawy",blank=True, default="", 
    max_length=200)
    DinnerComponents = models.CharField("Składniki",blank=True, default="", 
    max_length=20009)
    PizzaPrice = models.CharField("Rozmiar i cena Pizzy", 
    help_text="np.Mała-10zł", default="", blank=True, max_length=300) 
    Price = models.DecimalField("Cena",default="00", max_digits=5, 
    decimal_places=2)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Menu"
        verbose_name_plural = "Menu"
```

views.py

```
def create_place(request):
    form = PlaceForm()
    sub_form = MenuForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = PlaceForm(request.POST)
        sub_form = MenuForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and sub_form.is_valid():
            place = form.save(commit=False)
            place.location = sub_form.save()
            place.save()
    context = {
    'form': form,
    'sub_form': sub_form
    }
return render(request, 'posts/layout.html', context)
```

Forms.py

```
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Place
    fields = ('LocalName', 'LocalAdress', 'LocalNumberPhone','LocalHours',)

class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('Dinner','DinnerComponents','DinerCategory', 'Price',)
```

After filling in the form and clicking submit, an error will appear "NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_menu.place_id"

Comment: Just for clarification, is this how your code looks 1 to 1?  Because Python is indent delimited and there's a lot of oddities in your code if this is how it actually looks.  If your code is correctly formatted in your project please update the question to match the formatting of your local code.

Comment: You have to first save a `Place` then assign the saved place to the `Menu` and finally save the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first save a Place then assign the saved place to the Menu and finally save the menu.

```
if form.is_valid() and sub_form.is_valid():
    place = form.save()
    menu = sub_form.save(commit=False)
    menu.place = place
    menu.save()
```

That's because a `Menu` needs a `place` foreign key otherwise it cannot be saved.

(Note: why do you mix snake_case and CamelCase for your field names? It's terribly difficult to know how your model's properties are called. Python's  convention is snake_case for all properties/methods/variables)

Comment: @mredisax if it works for you, don't forget to upvote the answer.